# Select rows in onUpgrade method

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have created method to select rows using getReadableDatabase() and cursors, everything is working fine, but when I try to use that method in onUpgrade, my app is crashing.

Did someone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onUpgrade() is triggered by an attempt to open a database via the SQLiteOpenHelper.
getReadableDatabase() uses the SQLiteOpenHelper, so calling your method from onUpgrade will cause endless recursion, and a stack overflow.

So, you'll need a version of your method that uses the database passed into the onUpgrade() method instead of calling getReadableDatabase()

Comment: I have tried that before, but thanks to your answer I noticed that I was closing database in my method, so thank you for explaining this!